# Unable to load Tiles.xml in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, tiles

I'm not able to load tiles.xml in my application.
Below is my config files -

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">  
        <property name="viewClass">  
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView</value>  
        </property>  
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"  
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">  
        <property name="definitions">  
            <list>  
                <value>/tiles-defs.xml</value>  
            </list>  
        </property>  
    </bean>
```

There are no listeners wrt tiles framework in web.xml.

Exception is - .

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/xxx].[xxx]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet xxx threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess.getContainer(TilesAccess.java:124) [tiles-api-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess.getContainer(TilesAccess.java:107) [tiles-api-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
```

Jars used - **tiles-request-servlet.jar, tiles-template.jar, tiles-servlet.jar**

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a mistake in the tilesConfigurer definitions. 
Change it as follows:

```
<property name="definitions">  
    <list>  
        <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</value>  
    </list>  
</property>
```

and make sure you have the **tiles-defs.xml** file under

> your-war-file-name.war/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the tiles initializer in your `web.xml` file.

Please add `CompleteAutoloadTilesListener` and try,

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: we are not using tiles extras jar. is there any other solution?

Comment: I was initially using tiles-extras.jar. However, after server deployment, it was throwing Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.request.velocity.render.VelocityRendererBuilder. So tiles-extras dependency was replaced by above mentioned jars.

Comment: Wishing Good Luck ;-)